# Android- Saving Internal Storage to my created folder

Tags: android

I want to save my internal storage file into the folder create by my app . Please some one suggest me how it is possible.
My Code :

```
    File sub = new File("/sdcard/myfiles");
    sub.mkdirs();

    FileOutputStream fout;
    try {
        fout = openFileOutput("MyPrefs" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String data="Welcome to Android Internal Storage";
                fout.write(data.getBytes());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to save:

```
//write file
                                File log = new File("sdcard/MyDirectory/MyFile.txt");

                                try
                                {
                                    if (!log.exists())
                                    {
                                        //System.out.println("We had to make a new file.");
                                        log.createNewFile();
                                    }

                                    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(log, true);

                                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                                    bufferedWriter.write("dataaaa"+ "%" + "moreDataaa"+ "%" + "moreMoreDataaa");
                                    bufferedWriter.write("******************** " + "\n");
                                    bufferedWriter.close();



                                    //System.out.println("Done");
                                } catch (IOException e)
                                {
                                    //System.out.println("COULD NOT LOG!!");
                                }
```